# calling php function error from another file

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to call a function `getBMR()` which is in another file (`user.php`) with the following code and I'm getting an error:

> Using $this when not in object context )..

variables are set in the `process.php` file that I am calling the function in

`$a =$_POST["example"];`

Here is the code

`echo $this->getBMR($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f);`

Thanks, any help would be great.

class user
{

```
public function getBMR()
{
    switch ($this->gender){
                case 'Female':
                    $gender= 655 + (9.6 * $userWeight ) + (1.8 * $userHeight) - (4.7 * $userAge);
                    echo "<p>Your estimated daily metabolic rate is $gender </p>";
                    echo "<p>This means that you need rouhgly $gender calories a day to maintain your current weight.</p>";

                    break;
                    case 'Male':
                        $gender=66 + (13.7 *$userWeight) + (5 * $heuserHeightight) - (6.8 * $userAge);
                        echo "<p>Your estimated daily metabolic rate is $gender </p>";
                        echo "<p>This means that you need rouhgly $gender calories a day to maintain your current weight.</p>";

            }
```

}

Comment: Try `require(user.php);` at the top of `process.php`

Comment: can you show us the class which defines method `getBMR()`, the way you instantiate it (e.g. `$obj = new someClass();`) and how you're trying to use method `getMBR()`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this code is not part of class method.
Try this

```
require_once("user.php");
$a =$_POST["example"];
// rest of code
echo getBMR($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f);
```

you are not allowed to use "$this" since you are not in an object context which means you are not using "$this" within class method

Note that if "user.php" file is not in same directory as process.php you need to include relative/absolute path up to directory in which user.php file is such as:

```
require_once('../path/to/users/user.php');
```

Taken from https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object

Comment: Tried require_once it didnt work.. i have include at the moment and still nothing

Comment: Are you still getting any errors in your code? If so, write them down please. Also did you remove $this-> from the method call? Check logs for any additional errors please.

Comment: Call to undefined function getBMR()  is theerror im getting

Comment: I have removed $this-> from mehod file too

Comment: Can you include user.php file into the original question? We need to see the method definition

Comment: Oh okay, in your process.php, you need to instantiate new instance of class user. So `$user = new User(); echo $user->getBMR();`